# socket.io not connecting to backend with 404 error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, sockets, socket.io

I am trying to connect to my backend (localhost:5001) from my front end (localhost:5173). However, it keeps giving me error 404 cannot connect.

Here are my files below

```
// This file is imported into my react app.js
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

export const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:5001/");
```

and

```
require('dotenv').config();

const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const userRoutes = require('./routes/user');
const groupRoutes = require("./routes/group");
const forumRoutes = require("./routes/forum");
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

const http = require('http');
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
app.use(cors({
  origin: "http://localhost:5173"
}));
const server = http.createServer(app);
app.use(express.json());
const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: 'http://localhost:5173',
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
  }
});



io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log(`User connected ${socket.id}`);
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  // console.log(req.path, req.method);
  next();
});

app.use('/api/user', userRoutes);
app.use('/api/group', groupRoutes);
app.use('/api/forum', forumRoutes);

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI)
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
      console.log('listening on port', process.env.PORT);
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Is there anything that I am doing wrong or careless? thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The socket server is bound to the HTTP `server` instance created by `http.createServer(app)`, not the HTTP server instance created by `app.listen()`.

What does `app.listen()` method do? See the source code:

```js
app.listen = function listen() {
  var server = http.createServer(this);
  return server.listen.apply(server, arguments);
};
```

As you can see, it creates a new HTTP server instance.

It should be:

```js
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: 'http://localhost:5173',
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
  }
});
server.listen(process.env.PORT)
```

NOT:

```js
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: 'http://localhost:5173',
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
  }
});
app.listen(process.env.PORT)
```