# React hooks, typescript, mongoose, express and socket.io working together

Tags: reactjs, typescript, express, mongoose, socket.io

I am trying to get a frontend react app to connect with socket.io to NodeJS express api

```tsx
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import io from "socket.io-client";

const socket = io("http://localhost:4000");

const Chat: React.FC = () => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    // Evento para recibir mensajes del servidor
    socket.on("chat message", (msg: string) => {
      setMessages((prevMessages) => [...prevMessages, msg]);
    });

    return () => {
      // Limpia el evento al desmontar el componente
      socket.off("chat message");
    };
  }, []);

  const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    socket.emit("chat message", inputValue);
    setInputValue("");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Walkie Talkie Chat</h1>
      <ul>
        {messages.map((message, index) => (
          <li key={index}>{message}</li>
        ))}
        <li>final</li>
      </ul>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" value={inputValue} onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)} />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Chat;
```

```ts
import cors from "cors";
import express from "express";
import http from "http";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import socketio from "socket.io";

// Configurar Express
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

const PORT = 4000;

// Socket io
const server = http.createServer(app);
app.set("port", PORT);
const io = new socketio.Server(server);

io.on("connection", (socket: socketio.Socket) => {
  console.log("Nuevo cliente conectado");

  // Evento para recibir mensajes del cliente
  socket.on("chat message", (msg: string) => {
    console.log("Mensaje recibido: " + msg);

    // Emitir el mensaje a todos los clientes conectados, incluyendo al remitente
    io.emit("chat message", msg);
  });

  // Evento para manejar la desconexión del cliente
  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("Cliente desconectado");
  });
});

const dbName = process.env.dbName;
const dbUsername = process.env.dbUsername;
const dbPassword = process.env.dbPassword;

mongoose
  .connect(`mongodb+srv://${dbUsername}:${dbPassword}@cluster.something.mongodb.net/${dbName}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`)
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Conexión exitosa a la base de datos");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error al conectar a la base de datos:", error);
  });

app.get("*", (_, res) => {
  res.status(404).send("Nothing here");
});

// Iniciar el servidor
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Servidor iniciado en el puerto ${PORT}`);
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*"socket.io": "^4.7.1"*

You should use the `server` created by `http.createServer(app)` rather than the `app` to listen to the port. It's nothing to do with TypeScript and mongoose.

E.g.

```
import cors from 'cors';
import express from 'express';
import http from 'http';
import socketio from 'socket.io';

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

const PORT = 4000;
app.set('port', PORT);

const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new socketio.Server(server);

io.on('connection', (socket: socketio.Socket) => {
    console.log('Nuevo cliente conectado');
    socket.on('chat message', (msg: string) => {
        console.log('Mensaje recibido: ' + msg);
        io.emit('chat message', msg);
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('Cliente desconectado');
    });
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.get('*', (_, res) => {
    res.status(404).send('Nothing here');
});

server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Servidor iniciado en el puerto ${PORT}`);
});
```

`index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
        />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.5.4/socket.io.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var socket = io('http://localhost:4000');
            socket.emit('chat message', 'ok');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Logs on server-side:

```
Servidor iniciado en el puerto 4000
Nuevo cliente conectado
Mensaje recibido: ok
```

Also, see [socket.io not connecting to backend with 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76486873/socket-io-not-connecting-to-backend-with-404-error)